# Custom address type mailing label issue

Tags: civimail

Civicrm 4.6.5. When trying to create mailing labels, it works fine for primary address location, however when trying to use other location types or a custom location type we have created it just prints out a blank pdf page. There are several addresses that should be added (contacts have the fields populated). Any help in getting this working would be greately appreciated

Comment: Have you successfully replicated this issue using the demo server at http://demo.civicrm.org?  That's an important first step to isolate the problem to either your server or to the software.

Comment: I didnt even know that existed...

The issue is there too. I created a custom address type and assigned an address to it on a member (129), created a mailing label for this member and it produced a blank pdf. Looks like it is an issue with civicrm rather than my server. Anywhere I can log this?

Comment: Is there any easy way I can log this as an issue? I need to let my client know that it isn't something our end but more of an application issue that needs resolving but want to be able to say to them that this will be looked at?

Comment: You can report it via the issue queue (https://civicrm.org/issue-queue).  However, while CiviCRM is free to use, it's not free to write.  Your issue is unlikely to be fixed without submitting to the paid issue queue (https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) or submitting a patch yourself, which folks will help you with.